# Does anything suggest Ben 10 (2016) is part of the Ben 10 multiverse?

Tags: chronology, ben-10, ben-10-2016

In *Ben 10* we got to know there are multiple universes with multiple iterations of Ben 10 and even multiple future timelines too. That made me wonder, is even *Ben 10* (2016) part of that multiverse?

Is there any in or out of universe confirmation about it?